# Are there security measures against udp hole punching?

Tags: networking, udp, firewall, nat, hole-punching

I want to establish an UDP communication between two peers, say Alice and Bob. Alice is behind a port restricted cone NAT (so that the same internal port gets mapped to the same external port even if the destination is changed), while Bob is behind a symmetric NAT (which means that the external port will change every time a new destination is chosen regardless of the internal port, thus making the external port unpredictable). I have a server in between and I want to make an UDP hole punch.

I implemented the following strategy:

- Bob opens a large number of ports and from all of them sends a packet to Alice's external port (he gets to know if through the server).
- Alice sends packets to Bob's NAT at random ports until the connection is established.

Having two NATs of those types at hand, I did some experiments. Bob opens 32 ports, and Alice sends 64 packets every 0.1 seconds. The connection is usually established within 1 or 2 seconds, which is more than suitable for my needs.

However, I was wondering if I could get in trouble with some strict NAT routers or firewalls. On example, could it happen that a router won't allow an internal peer to open 32 ports? Or (and this sounds somehow more likely) could it happen that a router that sees a lot of packets incoming on random ports that get dropped will blacklist the ip and drop all its packets for some time? I read that sometimes this could happen in case of a DoS attack but my packet rate is something like 4 to 6 orders of magnitude lighter than a DoS attack.

I am asking about reasonable network configuration: I am pretty sure that in principle it is possible to setup a firewall to behave in that way. I will be targeting mainly users that lie behind standard home connections, so my main target is common internet providers that use NATs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interesting question.

**First of all**, I'm not sure anyone has the exact answer you're looking for. Different networks use different equipment and different configuration. Two ISPs can use ten different vendors for their routers, firewalls, NATs, intrusion detection equipment, DPI equipment etc; not to mention the number of possible configurations all of this equipment has.

And while commercial and corporate networks are bad enough, home networks are even worse. Here there are even more vendors selling modems, NAT boxes, and various software that affects network connectivity (such as firewalls and anti-viruses). All of which is in the hands of users who aren't technically savvy that leave it with the default settings, *or worse*.

Moreover, in both home and commercial networks there might be several layers of NAT. I know of a company that has a NAT for each lab (to isolate it from other labs and the R&D network). Each lab is then connected to the R&D NAT (to isolate it from other departments), which in turn is connected to the company-wide NAT, which, by the way, is also heavily firewalled. Add to that a possible ISP-level ([carrier grade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)) NAT, and you're looking at up to 4 layers of NAT. Hopefully this is an extreme example, but two layers of NAT are quite common nowadays with home NAT and carrier grade NAT.

Given that, how likely it is for a random network to consider this behavior suspicious and limit it? Frankly, I don't know for sure and I don't think anyone else does with a high degree of certainty.

Despite that, my educated guess is that sane default configurations of communication equipment (NATs, routers, etc) should not block such behavior. After all, many applications open several ports; not to mention the fact that the NAT has no way of knowing that the IP sending this traffic isn't itself a NAT device with dozens of computers behind it - each of them with several open ports.

I also guess that simple firewalls should be fine with it as long as UDP itself isn't blocked, and the usage of the various ports is allowed. Firewalls that attempt to block port-scanning, and anti-DDoS equipment, however, might pose a problem as this traffic might seem suspicious to it, so it might depend on the configuration/implementation details of such equipment and software. So unfortunately, the only way to tell how your strategy will behave in the real world it to try it out on a variety of different networks.

**Second**, I'd like to say a few words about your hole punching strategy. If both Alice and Bob have a shared server, and Alice is behind a cone NAT, I don't see the point in your strategy. A cone NAT is the simplest NAT to overcome. If you want Alice to be able to connect to Bob (which is tricky since he's behind a symmetric NAT), all you really have to do is to get Bob to connect to Alice upon Alice's request.

To do that, both Alice and Bob should always have a long-lasting TCP or UDP connection to the server. The connection shouldn't carry any data for the most part, and should be just kept alive once in a while.

When Alice wants to connect to Bob, it just opens a port (say port X), and connects from that port to the server. The server sees Alice's external port that corresponds to port X - say port Y. At this point, Alice informs the server that she would like Bob to connect to her. Since Bob is connected to the same server, the server informs Bob that it should connect to Alice at at port Y. This should establish a connection between them without the need for any guessing.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am glad that finally someone decided to answer to this question! Let me start with the second point: the kind of NAT you are referring to is the full cone NAT, that will just map an internal port X to an external port Y and will allow all packets incoming to port Y inside and will route them to the user inside the NAT on port X. However, this is not the case for a port restricted cone NAT, which has an uniform port mapping but will allow answers only from destinations to which it has sent a packet, from there the need of this dirty hole punch technique.

Comment: As for the first point: as far as I understand, a large part of the DNS traffic is based on UDP, is that right? (I also think this example could in principle be extended to TCP but I am not an expert) Now, if this kind of port scanning behaviors would be blocked by a NAT, there would be an easy way for an attacker to damage the quality of the network. One could spoof an incoming port scan attack, say, from the most known DNS servers, and get them blocked by the firewall with a really limited amount of resource, thus preventing all those inside to access that service!

Comment: 1. You're right about the NAT. I neglected the fact that the Cone NAT is port restricted. That does make matters more difficult. There are still solutions for this (based on port prediction e.g. http://www.goto.info.waseda.ac.jp/~wei/file/wei-apan-v10.pdf), but they're more complex.

Comment: 2. Yes. DNS is mostly UDP based, port 53 to be exact. And there are often exceptions for DNS traffic in firewalls that otherwise block UDP. But the attack you propose is a bit trickier than you think. A smart firewall might not block such traffic outright, but permit UDP from port 53 only, or check that that the packets look like DNS replies, or check whether they're coming from a known DNS server (the network operator might have a white-list). On the other hand, it it possible that the attack you're describing is indeed possible with some firewalls. It's hard to say without checking.

Comment: I had another though - you might want to try asking your question at http://security.stackexchange.com
Someone there will probably know whether your traffic might look like a known attack.

Comment: I actually did but I received no answer ;)

Comment: I had an idea that could work. What if I set the TTL of the packets that I am sending to punch from the cone high enough to pass through the NAT but low enough so that it doesn't actually reach the other endpoint? In this way I am still opening the restricted cone to the symmetric endpoint ports, but nothing actually gets to the symmetric endpoint and no attack can ever be detected! Could this work?

Comment: Sure, that could work on Bob's packets, but obviously not on Alice's (since they actually need to reach Bob). But you'd need a TTL low enough not to reach Alice, while being high enough for passing through Bob's NAT(s).

Comment: Sure, but the symmetric endpoint knows where to send its packets so it is okay if they actually reach the destination, they will not be detected as some port scan attack! Ok thank you: you made everything more clear!